# Limit displayed options in a dropdown using css

Tags: html, css, html-select

Is there any css property by which i can limit the displayed options in a dropdown.

I know that setting **size = 'value'** in select limits the displayed options in drpdown to that value. Is this achievable using css.

```
<select size="5">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
</select>
```

Using this the no of options visible will be limited to 5. Can this be done in css.
Actually I have a lot of dropdowns in my application and adding size to each of them is very time consuming and i may need to change the no of items displayed afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the selects you want to change:

```
<select class="limit">
...
</select>
```

Then using some jQuery:

```
$('.limit').attr('size', 5);
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/FG6QW/).

Comment: Adding a class to all selects would be as much work as adding a `size`  attribute.  To apply to all selects without using a class, use `$('select').attr('size', 5);` http://jsfiddle.net/FG6QW/1/

Comment: Sure. But unless the OP wants every single select to look like that, it would make more sense to target it to specific select elements that need it.